# Different routes for different subdomains in Nuxt.js

Tags: routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

Suppose there're two subdomains working for one nuxt instance. They should have different pages structure. For example it can be:

```
pages/
  index.vue // technical entry point that has some logic for determining what routes subtree should be used
  subdomain1/
    index.vue // entry point for subdomain1.mysite.com/
    page1.vue // entry point for subdomain1.mysite.com/page1
  subdomain2/
    index.vue // entry point for subdomain2.mysite.com/
    page1.vue // entry point for subdomain2.mysite.com/page1
    page2.vue // entry point for subdomain2.mysite.com/page2
```

The folder structure can be different. The goal is to be able to load different pages for different subdomains. `subdomain1.mysite.com/page1` has to load one file (e.g. `pages/subdomain1/page1.vue`) while `subdomain2.mysite.com/page1` has to load the other file (e.g. `pages/subdomain2/page2.vue`).

We can use `nuxtServerInit` action for determining the subdomain, so there's some `this.$store.state.ux.subdomain` variable that is eiter subdomain1 or subdomain2. But the rest is not clear for me.

Is it possible to achieve in nuxt.js? If it is, I suppose we should use named views `<nuxt-child :name="subdomain"/>` and `extendRoutes` in nuxt.config.js somehow, but I was not able to achieve it so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this one - desperately! If someone knows how to do this, please comment

Comment: I was able to `solve` this by defining the special project folder structure with site1, site2 and shared folders, symlinking the common files from shared folder and running 2 nuxt processes, one for site1 and the other one for site2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to handle multiple subdomains with nuxtJS. I have created a module [k-domains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-domains) for the same. you can [try it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-domains) or you can also achieve the same result by modifying the routes with the `@nuxtjs/router` module, check for the `request.header.host` and if it matches to your subdomain then filter the routes and remove the subdomain from the `route.name` and `route.path`

```js
newRoutes = options.routes
      .filter(route => {
        // remove routes from other directories
        const toRemove = subdomains.filter(domain => {
          return domain != routesDirectory
        })
        return !isUnderDirectory(route, toRemove);
      })
      .map(route => {
        // remove directory from path and name
        if (isUnderDirectory(route, routesDirectory)) {
          return {
            ...route,
            path: route.path.substr(routesDirectory.length + 1) || "/",
            name: route.name.substr(routesDirectory.length + 1) || "index"
          };
        }
        return route;
      });
```

check this [link](https://github.com/madhusudanbabar/k-domains/blob/master/lib/router.js) for exact router.js code. 
here is the [project link](https://github.com/madhusudanbabar/k-domains/) and here is the npm module [k-domains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-domains)

Here's the link to the [article](https://blog.madhusudan.live/blog/handling-multiple-sub-domains-with-nuxtjs-and-k-domains) for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

In your `pages/index.vue`, you should be able to switch the page you're using. But I would probably move the rest of the content outside of `/pages`, because those components are generated as different routes automatically. I'd do something like:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <component :is="currentPage" />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
// Dynamic imports will prevent both pages from being lodaded upfront
const page1 = () => import('@/components/views/page1')
const page2 = () => import('@/components/views/page2')

export default {

  computed: {
    currentPage() {}
      const currentSubdomain = this.$store.getters('ux.subdomain') // assuming you have a `getter` with that name
      return currentSubdomain === 'subdomain1' ? page1 : page2

  }
}
</script>
```

Note: I wrote this from the top of my head. Specific implementation may vary in your case ;)

And the folder structure would look like:

```
├── pages/
│   ├── index.vue
├── components/
    └── views/
         ├── page1.vue
         └── page2.vue
```